# D: decoding ubyte[] to string, redux

Tags: string, zip, d, decode, bytestream

This question is a modified redux of this previous question:

[how to decode ubyte[] to a specified encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649712/how-to-decode-ubyte-to-a-specified-encoding)

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to convert the `ubyte[]` array returned from a `std.zip.ArchiveMember.expandedData` attribute into a string or other range-able collection of strings... either the whole contents akin to calling `File.open("file")`, or something iterable in similar fashion to `File.open("file").byLine()`.

So far everything I've found from the standard documentation that deals with character arrays or strings does not appreciate a `ubyte[]` argument, and the examples around D's zip file handling are very rudimentary, dealing only with getting raw data out of zip archives and their member files... with no obvious file/stream/io interface capable of being easily layered between the raw bytestream and text-oriented file/string manipulation.

I think I can find something in `std.utf` or `std.uni` to decode individual code points, and while/for-loop my way through the bytestream, but surely there might be a better way?

Code sample:

```d
std.zip.ZipArchive zipFile;
// just humor me, this is what I've been given.
zipFile = new std.zip.ZipArchive("dataSet.csv.zip");
foreach(memberFile; zipFile.directory)
{
    zipFile.expand(memberFile);
    ubyte[] uByteArray = memberFile.expandedData;

    // ok, now what?
    // is there a relatively simplistic way to get this
    // decoded/translated byteStream into a string
    // or collection of strings(for example, one string per line
    // of the compressed file) ?

    string completeCsvContents = uByteArray.PQR();
    string[] csvRows = uByteArray.XYZ();
}
```

Is there anything that I could easily fill in for PQR or XYZ?

Or, if it's a matter of making an API call in the style of

```d
string csvData = std.ABC.PQR(uByteArray)
```

What would ABC/PQR be?

Comment: well, perhaps a bit more searching in a different direction was in order. seems Adam Ruppe has a module that may get the job done: [characterencodings.d](https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/characterencodings.d)

I'll try it out, and if it works decently, as it appears it should, then I'll answer my own question.

Comment: It depends what encoding the file is in. If it is already ascii or utf-8, you can simply cast it to `char[]`. If it is something else like Windows-1252 which Excel often saves as in English, then something like my characterencodings.d module will help you convert.

Comment: I came to that realization after skimming your source, I'd never worked with utf-8 in detail before so I wasn't sure what kinds of casting assumptions were safe to make. I appreciate your response, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it is safe to cast either if it is already valid (my function tryToDetermineEncoding does this check. UTF-8 validity is rare in a random byte stream, but other encodings are hard to figure out which is why that's all it returns), or only has all values `< 128`. It still isn't necessarily correct, but almost certainly is then. But any values >= 128 that aren't already utf8 encoding should not be casted - it would throw if you tried to use it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the string is UTF-8 encoded, you can use [`std.string.assumeUTF`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#.assumeUTF) to convert it to a string/char array. All this does is a cast, as Nested type mentions, but it's mode self-documenting.

If you need to make sure that the resulting string is actually valid UTF-8 (as there are several operations with undefined behavior on invalid strings), then you can use [`std.utf.validate`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_utf.html#.validate). `assumeUTF` also does this under debug builds.

Comment: I don't have one of the files on this machine, so I can't peek at the format, but that will be a nice safety check. Thank you. (and Nested Type )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just do

```
auto stuff = cast(char[]) memberFile.expandedData;
```

When using the resulting `char[] stuff` it will be auto decoded anyway, for example by the functions that will call the range primitives when passing this `char[] stuff` as input range.

Because actually neither `char[]` nor `string` are decoded. Only `dchar[]` or `dstring` are.